problems with sequelize intermediate table
10 days ago I come with this problem I run out of ideas. what happens is that I have a many to many relationship between the entities of orders and equipment that are borrowed. the problem is as follows, I OrdersEquipments model in which I request the id of each team and award them to the order to have a strict control. The problem is that in the forOf cycle when updating the fieldName with their respective model I load a column that should not be because it is not being requested which is pdasId as we will see in the console below:
beforeCreate console:

pcsId VAMOS BIEN OrdersEquipment {
  dataValues: { pdasId: null, orderId: 6, pcsId: 1 },
  _previousDataValues: { orderId: undefined, pcsId: undefined },
  uniqno: 1,
  _changed: Set(2) { 'orderId', 'pcsId' },
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: true,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    attributes: undefined,
    include: undefined,
    raw: undefined,
    silent: undefined
  },
  isNewRecord: true
}

CODE JS:
export const createOrder = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const {
      responsibility,
      event,
      note,
      state,
      userId,
      pdaCount,
      handiesCount,
      pcsCount,
      printHardCount,
      printPocketCount,
      celusCount,
      complementsCount,
    } = req.body;

    const selectEquipment = async (model, count) => {
      const availableEquipments = await model.findAll({ where: { userId: 1 } });
      if (availableEquipments.length < count) {
        throw new Error(
          `No hay suficientes equipos disponibles de tipo ${model.name}`
        );
      }
      return availableEquipments.slice(0, count);
    };

    const selectedPDAs = await selectEquipment(PDAS, pdaCount);
    const selectedCelus = await selectEquipment(CELUS, celusCount);
    const selectedPCs = await selectEquipment(PCS, pcsCount);
    const selectedPrintHards = await selectEquipment(
      HARDTICKET,
      printHardCount
    );
    const selectedPrintPockets = await selectEquipment(
      POCKET,
      printPocketCount
    );
    const selectedHandies = await selectEquipment(HANDIES, handiesCount);
    const selectedComplements = await selectEquipment(
      COMPLEMENT,
      complementsCount
    );

    if (
      selectedPDAs.length === pdaCount &&
      selectedCelus.length === celusCount &&
      selectedPCs.length === pcsCount &&
      selectedPrintHards.length === printHardCount &&
      selectedPrintPockets.length === printPocketCount &&
      selectedHandies.length === handiesCount &&
      selectedComplements.length === complementsCount
    ) {
      const newOrder = await ORDERS.create({
        responsibility,
        event,
        note,
        state,
        userId,
      });

      const assignEquipmentsToOrder = async (equipments, model) => {
        for (const equipment of equipments) {
          console.log(model.name)
          const fieldName = `${model.name.toLowerCase()}Id`;

          const newOrderEquipment = {
            orderId: newOrder.id,
            [fieldName]: equipment.id,
          };
    await ordersEquipmentModel.beforeCreate((newOrderEquipment) => {
        if (newOrderEquipment[fieldName] != null) {
          console.log(fieldName, "VAMOS BIEN", newOrderEquipment);
        } else {
          console.log("VAMO MAL", newOrderEquipment);
        }
      });
          await ordersEquipmentModel.create(newOrderEquipment);

          equipment.userId = userId;
          await equipment.save();
        }
      };

      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedPDAs, PDAS);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedPCs, PCS);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedPrintHards, HARDTICKET);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedPrintPockets, POCKET);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedCelus, CELUS);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedHandies, HANDIES);
      await assignEquipmentsToOrder(selectedComplements, COMPLEMENT);

      return res.status(200).json(newOrder);
    } else {
      throw new Error("No se pudieron asignar todos los equipos solicitados.");
    }
  } catch (error) {
    return res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
  }
};

MODEL:
import { DataTypes } from "sequelize";
import { sequelize } from "../../../database/database.js";
import ORDERS from "../orders/ordersModel.js";
import PDAS from "../equipos/pdas.js";
import CELUS from "../equipos/celus.js";
import PCS from "../equipos/pc.js";
import HARDTICKET from "../equipos/printHard.js";
import POCKET from "../equipos/printPocket.js";
import HANDIES from "../equipos/handies.js";
import COMPLEMENTARY from "../equipos/complementary.js";

const ordersEquipmentModel = sequelize.define(
  "OrdersEquipment",
  {
    orderId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: ORDERS,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: false,
    },
    celusId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: CELUS,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    pdasId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: PDAS,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    pcsId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: PCS,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    hardTicketId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: HARDTICKET,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    pocketId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: POCKET,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    handiesId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: HANDIES,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
    complementaryId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      references: {
        model: COMPLEMENTARY,
        key: "id",
      },
      allowNull: true,
    },
  },
  {
    timestamps: false,
  }
);


export default ordersEquipmentModel;



I hope you can understand it is the first time I post in a forum, thank you very much!
I tried modifying the model relationships but the error persisted, also the controller logic. The only way I found that it works is when I make the post request and I don't ask for any entity except the pdas in which the error is the following: “message”: “the null value in the column ‘pdasId’ of the relationship ‘OrdersEquipments’ violates the constraint of not null” and I tried adding the allowNull in the model orderEquipments and it didn't work either.`

It looks like the column "pdasId" has been defined as non-null, as I think you were able to determine. Are you able to share your model definitions? Also, did you sync your database after adding allowNull: true ?

hi, if i synchronized the base with the force: true and reloaded the data several times it still does not work. i share the ordersEquipments template

I don't know how to add another code block to this question, it's the first time I consult a forum.

See these instructions for how to edit your post: https://stackoverflowteams.help/en/articles/8858605-edit-a-question-or-answer.
To add a code block, every line of code just needs to start with at least 4 spaces.

here I added the model below the js code, tell me what do you think or what can it be?

It's a bit unusual to define your foreignKeys manually. Normally sequelize creates them automatically when you define the association. How and where are you defining your associations? In particular, how did you define the association with PDAS?
Also, what database engine are you using? Can you verify in your database management software whether the column pdasId has actually been set to non-null?
